# Show that the vector space $V$ over Field $R$ with a basis $B$ and vector space $\text{Map}[B,R]$ are isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Question:

> Show that the vector space $V$ over Field $R$ with a basis $B$ and vector space $\text{Map}[B,R]$ are isomorphic.

Show $V \cong  \text{Map}[B,R]$.

($\;\text{Map}[B,R] := \{f \in \text{Map}[B,R] : f(a) = 0 \;\,\text{up to many finite}\;\, a \in B\}\;$.)

I understand so far that in order for two vector spaces to be isomorphic, they have to have the same $\dim(V ) =n.$

What I can’t get through in the above question is how to show that $$\dim(\text{Map}[B,R])= n .$$

Thanks alot

Comment: Instead of showing same dimension, why not write down a linear bijection between them?  Use the definition of "basis".

Comment: Presumably $V$ is supposed to be finite-dimensional; otherwise the statement would be false in many cases.

Comment: So, let’s take Basis of V = ( u1, u2, …, un) and Let’s taken Basis of Map(B,R) to be W= ( w1, w2,…, wn) How can you show , the Vector spaces are then isomorphic through these Basis.